# Issue with lazy translation and Basic Blog in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been using the blog that comes with the [Django Basic Apps](http://code.google.com/p/django-basic-apps/) for quite some time now, and haven't had any problems until now.  The error I have been getting happens any time I try to access the single page for a newly created blog post.  Note that this is only happening for recently created posts; earlier posts work just fine.

This is the only thing Django tells me:

`No <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x105ab8890> found for`

I've done a bit more research and determined that Django has some sort of a [lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/) functionality, and that is the object that is not being found.  I'm still completely confused as to what parameter I could have changed that would suddenly cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added some `_()` [translated strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings) recently? Could you post the code, or an example of which creates this error?